# Stanford Ner API Details

Tags: stanford-nlp

Iam trying to find the Stanford Ner API
i could not find Stanford Ner API details 
in Stanford NLP website.

please can any body help to find out those
API

Where I can get Stanford Ner API.

Comment: Just visit the site listed below and it will solve ur problem. 
http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Stanford NER is included in the [Stanford NLP javadocs](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/). Or you can download release from the [Stanford NER page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/CRF-NER.shtml) and make javadocs from the sources.

Answer (score 0):

Stanford NER is library, you must download it, import for your project, all API is declared in file NERDemo.java.
You can get a CoreLabel object from result.